# How to create nested custom environment with different kind of frames?

Tags: macros, environments

So before I write ten pages describing what I'm looking to do, I made a small mock up:
[image]

I had something like this in mind:

```
\begin{mybox}[Name]
\begin{syntax}
  here comes source code
\end{syntax}
\begin{type}
  here come a few inference rules
\end{type}
\begin{kind}
  also inference rules
\end{kind}
\end{mybox}
```

So one big box, with a partial frame and a name. In the big box are three small boxes , each with a line at the top and a small box telling what it is.
Not every box should contain all three parts, e.g. some have no kinding part.
Also it should be possible to go over more than one page, since this boxes can get fairly huge.

I now the basic LaTeX stuff, but I have no idea where to start looking for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have started with a solution:

```
  \newenvironment{myownbox}[1]
 { 
    \rule{1pt}{2mm}\rule[2mm-1pt]{\linewidth-2pt}{1pt}\rule{1pt}{2mm}\par
    \hspace*{4pt}
    #1 \\
    \smallskip
    \hspace*{4pt}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-8pt}
 }
 {
    \end{minipage}%
    \medskip\par
    \rule{1pt}{2mm}\rule{\linewidth-2pt}{1pt}\rule{1pt}{2mm}%    
   } 
 \newenvironment{syntax}
 { 
   \par\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} 
   \makebox[\textwidth][r]{Syntax}
   \verbatim
 }
 { 
  \endverbatim
 }
 \newenvironment{type}
 { 
   \rule{\textwidth}{1pt} 
   \makebox[\textwidth][r]{Type}
   \begin{typefigure}
 }
 { 
   \end{typefigure}
 }
```

I will update it, when its finished. At the moment are the headlines (Syntax, Type) not framed and the position is not perfect.